# split text contains spaces but keeps words inside quotations as one unit

Tags: python, regex

I want to split text into list, where file name with spaces should be treated as a single item: example

```
s = 'cmd -a -b -c "file with spaces.mp4" -e -f'.split()
print(s)
```

output:

```
['cmd', '-a', '-b', '-c', '"file', 'with', 'spaces.mp4"', '-e', '-f']
```

desired output:

```
['cmd', '-a', '-b', '-c', '"file with spaces.mp4"', '-e', '-f']
```

I tried using some for loops but it gets nasty, is there a decent way using regex or anything else which doesn't looks ugly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the built-in `shlex` module, as such:

```
import shlex
s = shlex.split('cmd -a -b -c "file with spaces.mp4" -e -f', posix=False)
print(s)
```

The purpose of `posix=False` passed into `split` is to preserve the quotation marks around the multi-word file name, since your desired output formats it like that. If you don't want to preserve the quotes, you can remove the `posix` argument.

Comment: `posix=False` This is exactly what i wanted, beautiful :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, in this case I won't use regex. This is what [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) is for:

```
import shlex

s = shlex.split( 'cmd -a -b -c "file with spaces.mp4" -e -f' )
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
['cmd', '-a', '-b', '-c', 'file with spaces.mp4', '-e', '-f']
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html)

```
import shlex

data=('cmd -a -b -c "file with spaces.mp4" -e -f')

new=shlex.split(data)

print(new)
```

yields,

```
['cmd', '-a', '-b', '-c', 'file with spaces.mp4', '-e', '-f']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to match either:

- `"` eventually followed by another `"` (`"[^"]*"`), or
- any non-space characters (`\S+`):

```
input = 'cmd -a -b -c "file with spaces.mp4" -e -f'
output = re.findall('"[^"]*"|\S+', input)
```

Comment: This is actually a good answer, I don't know why someone down vote it, this has an advantage over other answers where i still get the file name with spaces including the quotations  `['cmd', '-a', '-b', '-c', '"file with spaces.mp4"', '-e', '-f']` , thank you